# I can't use a foreach loop twice in my code, why?

Tags: c#, foreach, queue

I am currently trying to learn C# and I am giving it a shot to implement `Queue` from scratch.

Currently I am trying to implement `foreach` functionality so I can print out my queue.
I have an issue when I use a `foreach` loop twice in my code it wont print anything the second time I use it. I have managed to see that my `Current` method in the `Queue` class isn't being used the second time I use the foreach loop (*with help of the print statement of the `int` position variable, which doesnt print out anything the second time a foreach is being used*).

I appreciate any help to understand why I can't use a foreach loop twice in my code. And if there is anything else which can be improved with my code, that would be greatly appreciated as well.

The **RunTest** class below is where I test my implementation of my `Queue` class.

```
namespace RunTest
{
    class RunTest
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args){

            Queue<string> queueOfStrings = new Queue<string>();

            queueOfStrings.Enqueue("Dog");
            queueOfStrings.Enqueue("Cat");
            queueOfStrings.Enqueue("Mouse");
            queueOfStrings.Enqueue("Bird");

            System.Console.WriteLine("Foreach: \n");
            foreach(string item in queueOfStrings){
                System.Console.WriteLine(item);
            }
            System.Console.WriteLine("\n");

            System.Console.WriteLine("Peek: "+queueOfStrings.Peek());
            System.Console.WriteLine("Dequeue : "+queueOfStrings.Dequeue());
            System.Console.WriteLine("Peek: "+queueOfStrings.Peek());

            System.Console.WriteLine("Foreach: ");
            foreach(string item2 in queueOfStrings){
                System.Console.WriteLine(item2);
            }


        }
    }
}
```

And here is my `Queue` class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Queue<T> : IEnumerator,IEnumerable{

private LinkedList<T> list = new LinkedList<T>();
private T[] storeElements;

private int position = -1;

public Queue()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Queue initialized \n");
    
}

public void Enqueue(T data){

    list.AddFirst(data);

}



public int Count(){
    return list.Count;
}

public void Clear(){
    list.Clear();
}

public T Dequeue(){
    T data = list.Last.Value;
    list.RemoveLast();
    return data;
}

public T Peek(){
    return list.Last.Value;
}

private void ToArray(){
    storeElements = new T[Count()];
    list.CopyTo(storeElements, 0);
    Array.Reverse(storeElements);
}


//IEnumerator and IEnumerable require these methods.
public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
{
    ToArray();
    return (IEnumerator)this;
}
//IEnumerator
public bool MoveNext()
{
    position++;
    return (position < Count());
}
//IEnumerable
public void Reset()
{
    position = 0;
}
//IEnumerable
public object Current
{
    get { System.Console.WriteLine(position); return storeElements[position];}
}
}
```

Comment: **[Using the free, built-in Step Debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx)** to debug your code is easier than you think.  It will also help you learn how code executes which will help you write better code.

Comment: Just use the built in Queue object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the queue itself as the enumerator isn't a great idea-- it will really limit how the class can be used. Imagine for example if you wanted to check the queue for duplicates-- you'd have to create a nested loop, which means two simultaneous enumerators. It simply wouldn't work because there is only one `position` variable.

Take a look at how [built-in classes](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/array.cs) do it. They return a new instance of a separate enumerator class (e.g. an array will create a `SZArrayEnumerator`). In your case, you can probably leverage the enumerator provided by the backing field itself, like this:

```
public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
{
    ToArray();
    return storeElements.GetEnumerator();
}
```